# Need help in revising the code: Java FileIO

Tags: java, string, file-io, bufferedreader, filereader

I need help in revising the code. Given that on a notepad, written is the First Name Middle Initial and Last Name. The code that was created was like these:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Names{
public static void main (String args [])throws IOException{

    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Names.txt"));
    String a = f.toString();
    String name[] = new String[a.length()];
    String n = f.readLine();

    int x = 0;
    while (n!= null){
        name[x] = n;
        String names[] = new String[a.length()];

        for (int z = 0; z< name[x].length()-1; z++){
            if (name[x].charAt(z) == '.'){
            names[0] = name[x].substring(0,z-2);
            for (int bry = z-2; bry < name[x].length()-1; bry++){
                if (name[x].charAt(bry) == ' '){
                    names[1] = name[x].substring(z-2,bry);
                    for (int bry2 = bry; bry2<name[x].length()-1; bry2++){
                        if (name[x].charAt(bry2) == ' '){
                            names[2] = name[x].substring(bry2,      
  name[x].length());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
        System.out.println("First Name: " + names[0]);
        System.out.println("M.I: " + names[1]);
        System.out.println("Family Name: " + names[2] + "\n");
        n = f.readLine();
        x++;

    }

}
}
```

I would like to display the first name middle and last. Thanks for helping.

Comment: what is the issue and what is the separator between first, middle and last name?

Comment: What's the current output and what's the input from the `names.txt` file?

Comment: @Sybren: Lets say that this are the names that were input on the names.txt :

Erwin Jacob A. Watson
John Jason B. Watsan
Bryan B. Riben
Yasuo Riven D. Teemo


Expected Output:

First Name: Erwin Jacob
M.I: A.
Last Name: Watson

First Name: Bryan
M.I: B.
Last Name: Riben

First Name: Erwin Jacob
M.I: A.
Last Name: Watson

First Name: Yasuo Riven
M.I: D.
Last Name: Teemo

Comment: As suggested in other answers look a `String.split()`

Comment: As suggested in my answere just split the String at the whitespaces. My solution should work instantly for your pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() method of String. The revised code would look like this

```
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Names.txt"));
    String n = f.readLine();
    while (n != null)
    {
        String[] names = n.split("\\s");
        System.out.println("First Name: " + names[0]);
        System.out.println("M.I: " + names[1]);
        System.out.println("Family Name: " + names[2] + "\n");
        n = f.readLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with `String.split()`. If your Textfile looks like: "Tom TW Wellbrock" I would seperate the input String at the whitespaces. If your Attributes are seperated with a comma, split it there:

```
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Names.txt"));
    String input = fileReader.readLine(); //please choose other names for you variables they are confusing

     while (input != null){

      String[] parts = input.split(" "); //you can seperate with any Symbol
      System.out.println(parts[0]) //your first name
      System.out.println(parts[1]) //your initial
      System.out.println(parts[2]) //your last name
      input = fileReader.readLine();
     }
```

Comment: @Rahul Yadav where will I get the index number? for names [0] , [1] and [2]

Comment: @BlackHusky as you have used the spilt method of string it would return array of size 3 with zero based index so 0,1,2

Comment: well i think you wanted to ask me :D the method Strin.split() seperates your string in seperate String Arrays "1 2 3 4" -> array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2 ... In your case the first array(at index 0) will be your first name, the second array your initial and the last your family name

Comment: @tomwellbrock How about if there was a second name? Like Bryan Dexter T. Watson which should display like these:

First Name: Bryan Dexter
M.I.: T.
Last Name: Watson

Comment: That would be a problem. You could change the pattern of your txt file to "Bryan Dexter, T., Watson" and seperate at the comma. otherwise you could check the `.lenght` of your array if lenght is bigger than 3 firstname = array[0] + " " + array[1]

Comment: @tomwellbrock Im really having problems regarding about that. Anyways Thanks :)